# FreeBSD 10 Can't access /usr/ports via cd

Tags: freebsd

Something strange happened, as usual I entered:

```
cd /usr/ports/foo/bar && sudo make install clean
```

But after getting update via `portsnap fetch update` I can't change into `/usr/ports/foo/bar`. Should I just grant me permissions all sub-directories of `/usr/ports`? Or is there another possibility to fix this?

Comment: Has the port in question been moved/removed?

Comment: No, nothing was moved. And this concerns every folder in /usr/ports/, this means I can cd until the specific folder, e.g. ntop: cd  /usr/ports/net is possible but not cd /usr/ports/net/ntop

Comment: What do you mean by "can't"?  What's the error you're getting?

If it's a permissions problem - sure, you can use chmod.  The ports system is public anyway.

Comment: Yes, permissions denied problem. But I just want to knwo why this happend.

Comment: Does every subfolder have this issue or just recently-extracted ones? Maybe someone ran `portsnap update` after having run `umask 077` or something.

Comment: as I understand, portsnap removes folder, so your actual path (/usr/ports/foo/bar) is invalid. Just change directory to valid location (ex. /usr/ports), then back to port in question.

Comment: Switching between valid/ accessable folder and invalid ones didn't work.
Every subfolder was affected, so I changed the permissions to get access to the folders and that fixed it for me...